# Nested Menu GUI Issue

Tags: java, user-interface, menu

I'm doing an assignment regarding GUI's in java, and I have an issue.

I'm supposed to create a nested menu. That's fine and I can do that, but I've come across an issue.

If I add the same `JMenuItem` to two JMenu objects, it only shows up on one of the menus when I run the program.

EG: object1 and object2 are JMenu objects. color1 is a JMenuItem object.

```
object1.add(color1);
object2.add(color1);
```

When this happens and I compile the program to check out the GUI, only object2 has color1 listed.

**How can I make it so that both object1 and object2 menus display color1 on the GUI? Is there a way to do that without having to create a large amount of JMenu objects?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An instance of a `Component` (or in your case `JMenuItem`) can only belong to a single parent (or in your case `JMenu`).

You will need to create new instances of the `JMenuItem` for each menu you want to add them to...

Comment: So my only answer is to create a bunch of new objects?

Comment: You could take a look at the [`Actions` API](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/action.html) which would allow you to create a single instance of the required `Action` which would then be passed to multiple instance of `JMenuItem`, but essentially, yes...